# Flutter package management?

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

I have a flutter project and multiple packages in different folders is there is a way to manage them in one place. As of now, I navigate to a particular package folder(pubspec.yaml) add, update them. I think doing like this is a tedious task. Any solution to optimize it?

```
- root(hello_flutter)
- pubspec.yaml
-- packages
  -- pck1
     -- pubspec.yaml
 -- pck2
     -- pubspec.yaml
 -- pck3
     -- pubspec.yaml
....
```

Comment: Are you trying to develop a flutter application with dependencies, or develop multiple co-dependent library packages at once?

Comment: @AlexMeuer Assume I have getx in pck1 and pck3, some UI packages in pck2, and root pubspec.yaml what if I want to update getx in both folders?

Comment: `Melos` sounds like what you want: https://medium.com/flutter-community/managing-multi-package-flutter-projects-with-melos-c8ce96fa7c82

Comment: @AlexMeuer Yeah i read about it . Have you ever used it ?

Comment: No, I looked into it a few years ago, but I figured it was better to start off with everything in one package ([KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)) to reduce complexity and then refactor into multiple packages _if_ I needed to later on down the line (I didn't).